# mysql query: how to get the number of yes/no votes per day

Tags: mysql

I have to create a mysql query to get a voting distribution of each day exceeding a particular date, something like this...

```
    date          yes_votes    no_votes
------------------------------------------
    2010-01-07    21           22
    2010-01-07    2            0
```

My table is like this..

```
    post_votes
--------------------------
    id(longint)
    date(timestamp)
    flag(tinyint) // this stores the yes/no votes 1-yes, 2-no
```

I am stuck at this....

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, DATE(date) FROM post_votes WHERE date > '2010-07-01' GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

this gives the total number of votes per day, but not the distribution that I want.

Comment: Can you make it more clear? I doubt I understand your question.

Comment: The second row in your wanted result table should be `2010-02-07 , 2 , 0` , right?

Comment: @ypercude - Yeah! that silly copy-paste again :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
     , DATE(date)
     , SUM(flag = 1) AS yes_votes
     , SUM(flag = 2) AS no_votes
FROM post_votes 
WHERE date > '2010-07-01' 
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

This is a trick that works in MySQL, as `flag=1` will either be `True` or `False`. But `True = 1` and `False = 0` in MySQL so you can add the 1s and 0s using the `SUM()` function.

Other solutions with `IF` or `CASE` would be better for clarity or if there is any chance you want to move the database to another RDBMS.

Comments not related to the question:

- It's bad habit to use reserved words like `date` or `count` for naming fields or tables.
- It's also not good to use "date" when you actually store a timestamp. Names should reflect use.
- For table names it's recommended to use singular (`post_vote`) and not plural - although many use plural, it gets confusing in the end. Plural is good for some fields or calulated fields, like your `yes_votes` and `no_votes` where we have a counting.

Answer (score 5):

Sum it:

```
select date(date) as date,
       sum(case when flag = 1 then 1 else 0) as yes,
       sum(case when flag = 2 then 1 else 0) as no
from post_votes
where date > '2010-07-01'
group by date(date)
```

Answer (score 4):

you are almost at the solution :)

i would recommend the use of an `IF` condition in a `SUM` method like so:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(flag = 'yes',1,0)) AS yes_count,
       SUM(IF(flag = 'no',1,0)) AS no_count, 
       DATE(date) 
FROM post_votes 
WHERE date > '2010-07-01' 
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

this will allow for the function to add 1 to each sum only if the value is equal to `yes`/`no`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DATE(date) as dt,
sum(if(flag=1,1,0)) as yes,
sum(if(flag=2,1,0)) as no
FROM post_votes WHERE date > '2010-07-01' 
GROUP BY dt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too. The best solution of that I can think of, is to split the "flag" in two fields, like:

```
upvote(tinyint)
downvote(tinyint)
```

Then you are able to count them very easy and without mysql-voodoo:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(upvote) AS up,
  SUM(downvote) AS down,
  DATE(`date`) AS Created_at
FROM post_votes 
WHERE Created_at > '2010-07-01' 
GROUP BY Created_at
```

Btw.: You should not name a column `date`, because it's a MySQL-Keyword.